# Implementing Hover Intent

Tags: javascript, jquery, hoverintent

I just finished developing this Wordpress theme:
http://www.minnesdiner.com/

Everything is working well, but I'm not 100% happy with the navigation.
The sliding position indicator works smoothly, but I'd like to integrate the [hover intent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html) jQuery plugin to prevent the sliding indicator from sliding when the user unintentionally passes over the nav.

Any ideas as to how I could integrate this plugin? I'm currently firing a separate jQuery function for each nav item and passing coordinates to the sliding indicator based on which item is being hovered upon.

Here's my current jQuery code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

        var $currentpos = $("#menu-indicator").css("left");
        $("#menu-indicator").data('storedpos', $currentpos);

        $(".current-menu-item").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: $currentpos}, 150);
        });
        $(".menu-item-26").delay(500).mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: "52px"}, 150);
        });
        $(".menu-item-121").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: "180px"}, 150);
        });
        $(".menu-item-29").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: "310px"}, 150);
        });
        $(".menu-item-55").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: "440px"}, 150);
        });
        $(".menu-item-27").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: "570px"}, 150);
        });
        $(".menu-item-164").mouseenter(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().animate({left: "760px"}, 150);
        });

        $delayamt = 400;
        $("#header-row2").click(function () {
        $delayamt = 5000;
        });
        $("#header-row2").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#menu-indicator").stop().delay($delayamt).animate({left: $currentpos}, 600);
        });

});
```

As you can see, I need to bind mousover and mouseout to separate elements (list-item and containing div).

Thanks!

Comment: Post your code, please. I've implemented something similar in another question, see if that helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5697718/jquery-menu-hover/5697749#5697749

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want to do is avoid the user triggering the slide by mousing over the nav, I would just `setTimeout` in your hover function to call your sliding code after a certain amount of time has passed, and clear the timeout on the mouseout event. No extra plugin needed.

For example:

```
var hover_timer;
$('.menu-item').hover(
    function() {
        hover_timer = setTimeout(function() { 
            ... 
        }, 500);
    },
    function() { clearTimeout(hover_timer); }
);
```

**EDIT:** by the by, you should be combining all those hover functions into one. You can do something like:

```
$('.menu-item-26').data('slider-pos', '52px');
$('.menu-item-121').data('slider-pos', '180px');
...
```

And then in the code to slide, call it back:

```
$this = $(this);
$('#menu-indicator').stop().animate({left: $this.data('slider-pos')}, 150);
```

And that's just a start - you can generalize it even more, I bet.

Comment: Thanks! That seems like a good solution. Will I need to create a separate hover_timer variable for each menu item?

Comment: Ok... I tried to implement it. Anything look wrong here? http://www.minnesdiner.com/wp-content/themes/minnes_diner/inc/navigation_slider.js

Comment: you're only attaching the handler to `menu-item-26`. try `$('.menu-item')` instead

Comment: (ignore the comment that I just deleted :)

Comment: @coryetzkorn - eek, sorry, I had the arguments for `setTimeout` switched. Should work now.

Comment: I think we're close! http://www.minnesdiner.com/wp-content/themes/minnes_diner/inc/navigation_slider.js

Comment: Yup! so, the scope of `$list_item = $(this)` is wrong. You need to set it outside of the `setTimeout` function, just one level above. The reason is that inside `setTimeout`, `this` actually refers to `window`.

Comment: Beautiful! Thanks so much for your help. The site is now 100% how I imagined. Rock on!